# Rigging a handmade skeleton/rig

Tags: uv, rigging

've been trying to get a solid walking animation. I found one on Mixamo that seemed to work well, but I can't color it at all, as my creation on the left is made up of different, separate shapes and rigged, giving me autonomy over each pieces color and material.

How to get my model rigged to the mixamo (purple) walking rig

[image: both models]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask only one question per post, make as many as necessary.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hi, I have edited the question, so can you check it out and see if it can be reopened again?

Comment: I also updated, thank you for the info and sorry for the mistake